# Set a date from the subtraction of the same - Java

Tags: java, date

I'm doing a calendar / organizer in java

This calendar / organizer features as inputs
Event setup time
Date / Time of event begins
Date / Time Event finish

I can not mark two events in the same period.

Solved this problem by consulting this link [How can I determine if a date is between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883060/how-can-i-determine-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates-in-java)

My doubts on how to determine date with setup time and date / time of the event beginning.

What I need is a date start (12/12/12 00:00:00) subtracting time setup (00/00/01 00:00:00) have this (12/12/11 00:00:00)
**sorry my bad english

Comment: Just to confuse a little more, you could consider something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677541/date-range-in-date-range/20678485#20678485)

Comment: Really the question was too confusing.
What I need is from a date (12/12/12 00:00:00) by subtracting (00/00/01 00:00:00) have this (12/12/11 00:00:00)
Thanks for the link, I will search it

Comment: Do you want to substract 1 from the day?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for hundreds of examples of adding and subtracting date-time values. Search for "Java date add" or "Java date subtract". Bonus tip: focus on answers with "Joda" or "java.time".

Answer (score 0):

You can use *java.util.Date.getTime()* to find a *long* representation of date and then do a simple comparison or arithematic.